# Using C#, LINQ - want to get column names AND data values

Tags: c#, linq

I want to display, in a fairly generic manner, the contents of one row; I'll be using this technique against a few different tables.  The output will be plain text (in a RichTextBox), something like this:
TABLE_NAME
PROPNUM: xxxxxxx
SALE DATE: mm/dd/yyyy
...
LAST COL: lastvalue

(a) I know the column names for each table, but really don't want to hard-code them;
(b) I'd like it to be flexible enough to work if the table structures change.

I've figured out how to iterate through the column names - but not how to reference the corresponding data values!

```
var arQuery = (from acp in ... select acp).FirstOrDefault(); // one & only one match
foreach (var colName in arQuery.GetType().GetProperties())
...
```

colName now gets each column name, in turn; how do I then reference the corresponding value, in arQuery, for that column?  (Note: I'm perfectly happy to turn this on its head, and iterate through each column's value ... if I knew how to get to the column name for each value...)(Yes, I'm kinda new to C# and LINQ ... be kind, please!)

Thanks!

Comment: ASP.NET MVC has some nifty code for resolving the label for a property on a model object.  Since it's open source, you could peek at the code for `LabelExtensions.LabelFor` if you were so inclined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be possible like this:

```
//long way
string sline=arQuery.GetType().Name + " ";
foreach (PropertyInfo info in arQuery.GetType().GetProperties())
{
   if (info.CanRead)
   {
      sline += info.Name+": "+info.GetValue(arQuery, null) + " ";
   }
} 

//using LINQ without the for loop
sline += string.Join(" ", arQuery.GetType().GetProperties().Where(i=>i.CanRead).Select(i=> ""+i.Name+": "+i.GetValue(arQuery, null)));
```

Hope there are not too many typos ;)

Comment: Both did exactly what I expected, but the foreach gives me control over each value - I want to ignore null values and some irrelevant columns.  Thank you!!!